# How to use foreach for two c# listbox?

Tags: c#

I have two listbox in c# windows application,and i write this code for listbox1:

```
foreach(var item in listBox2.Items){

                try
                {
                    messagebox(item);//from listbox2
                    //i want write this messagebox(item2) from listbox1

                }catch(Exception ){

                }

            }
```

i want write something comment up code,notice listbox 1 and 2 have equal count of value,for example if listbox 1 have 30 parameter,sure listbox 2 have 30 parameter.thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by _i want write this messagebox(item2) from listbox1_ exactly? Can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easiest to iterate a counter and access the listbox items using an index

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox2.Items.Count; i++)
{
    try
    {
        messagebox(listBox2.Items[i]);        
        messagebox(listBox1.Items[i]);
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

Comment: I'm beginner in c#,please wait for test that